# Globally Initialized controls turns null in different method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, global-variables

I am declaring few variables at top and those are being initialized in `onCreate` method, when I am using those in different method those are returning `null`

code below in always showing *"Controls becomes null.."* result.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    EditText txtUsername,txtPass;
    Button btnLogin;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
        EditText txtPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
        Button btnLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        txtUsername.setText("Arvind");
        txtPass.setText("1234");

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                doLogin();
            }
        });
    }

    void doLogin()
    {
        if(txtUsername!=null || txtPass!=null) {
            if (txtUsername.getText() != null && txtPass.getText() != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully logged in..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password can't be empty..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Controls becomes null..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing at wrong way,
If you are declaring as global variable then why you should again declare new variable in local in `onCreate()` method

You have to use same variable as declare global and not to create new one.

look at this,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    EditText txtUsername,txtPass;
    Button btnLogin;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
        txtPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
        btnLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        txtUsername.setText("Arvind");
        txtPass.setText("1234");

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                doLogin();
            }
        });
    }

    void doLogin()
    {
        if(txtUsername!=null || txtPass!=null) {
            if (txtUsername.getText() != null && txtPass.getText() != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully logged in..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password can't be empty..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Controls becomes null..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to know that it helps. Happy coding :)

Comment: not my question, just saying my answer was wrong :D

Comment: @r15 No problem it happens, Please up vote and accept if it will help you

Comment: @r15, no worries! We all do stupid things every now and then. Happy coding!